# XMXtiledmap getLayer() return null with tmx file in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, tiled

I am using tiled map editor to get a `tmx` file and loaded that into my game which is developed with cocos2d-x c++  version 3.15.1

Here is the tmx file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" tiledversion="1.0.2" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="7" height="7" tilewidth="100" tileheight="100" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="map.tsx"/>
 <layer name="gamemap" width="7" height="7">
  <data encoding="csv">
2,2,1,2,2,2,1,
2,2,2,2,2,1,1,
1,1,1,1,2,1,1,
1,1,2,1,1,2,1,
1,2,2,2,2,2,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

And I use that with following code:

```
auto tmap = TMXTiledMap::create("map/map.tmx");
auto layer = tmap->getLayer("gamemap"); //null here
auto size = tmap->getMapSize(); 
CCLOG(" %f, %f", size.height, size.width);
auto sprite = layer->getTileAt(Vec2(1, 1));
```

I can confirm that `tmap` was loaded successfully, but `layer` is `null` with inspect to the local variables in the debugger.

I have tried different `tmx` format such as `xml` and `base64` but they all give some result.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: file location of your `map.tmx` file. ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan thanks for reply，I put it under resource/map/map.tmx since I could get the size of it correctly，location seems not the reason cause the problem

Comment: I think it should be inside `Resources/map/`

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes indeed, sorry for the typo texting on a mobile device now

Comment: what is the output of  `CCLOG("Total Layers %i ",tmap->getLayerNum());`

Comment: @AbhishekAryan sorry for the delay of response, but the `getLayerNum()` gives the count of layers `1`, which is expected :D

Answer (score 0):

I have found this out that not only I should put the tmx file in the source folder but also I have to import tileset file tsx file in the same folder and as well as the image that I loaded as a tileset file too. but the error message that cocos2dx gives could be a misleading for the solution. My bad to not got tiled map fully understand.

[image]