# Cocos2d-x TiledMap, return a nullptr when invoking getLayer() to get the collision layer?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, null-pointer

I have been struggling with the `null` pointer for hours! It happened when I used the `getLayer()` method to get a layer from the tiled map in cocos2d-x (the tailed map is edited using the Tailed Map Editor).

```
map = TMXTiledMap::create("map/map1.tmx");
map->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5, 0.5));
map->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2, visibleSize.height / 2 - 40));
this->addChild(map, 0, 100);
collidable = map->getLayer("collide")
collidable->setVisible(false);
```

The program didn't find the "collide" layer (it's a tiled layer) in my tailed map. However, it indeed exists in the `TMX` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" tiledversion="1.1.5" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="24" height="18" tilewidth="40" tileheight="40" infinite="0" nextlayerid="14" nextobjectid="2">

 <tileset firstgid="1" name="Background" tilewidth="40" tileheight="40" tilecount="7" columns="7">
  <image source="mapItems/background.png" width="280" height="40"/>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="8" name="tiles" tilewidth="40" tileheight="40" tilecount="16" columns="8">
  <image source="mapItems/tiles.png" width="320" height="80"/>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="24" source="mapItems/collide.tsx"/>
 <layer id="5" name="background" width="24" height="18">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   ...(some code)
 </layer>
 <layer id="11" name="collide" width="24" height="18">
  <properties>
   <property name="collidable" value="true"/>
  </properties>
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   ...
  </data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="6" name="bricks" width="24" height="18">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   ...
  </data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="7" name="tops" width="24" height="18">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   ...
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Moreover, I set breakpoint in the `getLayer()` method, and the program traverses and find all layers except the collide layer. Anyone can show me how to deal with this issue?

Comment: The TMX file you show seems incomplete. You don't need to show us the complete file, and even add ellipsis (`...`) for unimportant sections, but at least don't chop it up with incomplete tags.

Comment: Thanks for advise!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636472/xmxtiledmap-getlayer-return-null-with-tmx-file-in-cocos2dx

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Well, actually I put all my resources files in a correct way, but anyway thank you two, I've solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I solve this problem (4 hours since it occurred)... Despite I don't even know why.
The solution is editing the collide.tsx file. I tried to read it and found a sentence:

```
 <image source="collide.png" trans=ff00ff width="40" height="40"/>
```

And this "trans=" seemed quite weird... So I deleted it. Then the issue was resolved.

Comment: It should probably be `trans="ff00ff"`, with the value in double-quotes.